# Relatively Positioned Anchor (IE Woes)

Tags: internet-explorer, css-position, anchor

I am positioning an anchor like so:

```css
#test-link {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100px
}
```

As I need it so that when I visit `#test-link` the page jumps down to that particular section, but 100px higher. Otherwise the page scrolls too far down for what I need.

This works fine in decent browsers, however in IE7, 8 and 9 the relative positioning gets completely ignored.

I've tried different ways to fix it such as adding text to the anchor as well as various CSS properties (e.g. `display: block`) however nothing makes any difference.

Comment: Could you please share the markup of, and surrounding, your target element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure enough, IE7 through IE10 don't go to the relatively-positioned element (but rather to its natural location). There is one exception, IE8 worked just as I had expected. Nearly every browser I checked other than IE worked as expected as well.

This appears to be an issue with *relative* positioning, as attempting this with *absolute* positioning works just fine in IE6 through IE10. This of course doesn't help your situation since you're trying with relative positioning.

The only solution I have found after playing around with this for a while is to replicate relative positioning using margins:

```
#movedElement {
    display: block;
    margin: -100px 0 100px;
}
```

This gave *smiliar* results to those we see in other browsers, in all versions of IE. This isn't ideal, I understand, but it may suffice until better information is found.

I'll continue to research this, and return when I learn more.

#### You Could Use `padding` for *Padding*

In the meantime, another common approach to adding some whitespace before your target-area is to add margins to expand the space above that element. This is what I've done in the example viewable online at http://jsfiddle.net/Px6r9/1/show/#foo.

```
#paddedContent {
    padding-top: 50px; /* Adds whitespace above content */
}
```